# Simple first-child js?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Searching for a simple **first-child detection via javascript** (no framework).

**It should add class "`first`" for the first child of the element.** Like a css-hacks for ie, but in javascript and for a html file.

Must work similar to `:first-child`

When I say no framework, I mean some code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.documentElement.id = "js"</script>
```

---

For example:

```
<div class="terms">
    <dl>
        <dt>Term 1 name</dt>
        <dd>Term 1 description</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Term 2 name</dt>
        <dd>Term 2 description</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Term 3 name</dt>
        <dd>Term 3 description</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Three `<dl>`, the first one includes Term 1.

This css won't work in IE6, thats why I'm searching for a javascript solution. CSS-hacks are not allowed.

```
.terms dl:first-child { float: right; }
```

Comment: In what situations does this need to apply?  Elements already present in the document when it is loaded?  New items that are added dynamically?  Elements identified by a given class, or all elements?

Comment: I thought I understood your question until the last sentence. What's that Javascript snippet supposed to do?

Comment: %Bears will eat you, this javacsript just and example "how it should look like". I have no framework, so supposed to use an ordinary javascript.

Comment: you can use the '@' symbol to direct a comment to a user in the previous comments. this results in the user being directly notified that a comment has a reply. Also, the way the comment engine works you only need to provide the first few unique characters in the user's name. So `@bears` would be sufficient to reply to 'Bears will eat you'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want but you really do need to add an `id` to the div to facilitate finding it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .terms { }
        .terms dl.first { float: right; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="terms" class="terms">
        <dl>
            <dt>Term 1 name</dt>
            <dd>
                Term 1 description</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>Term 2 name</dt>
            <dd>
                Term 2 description</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>Term 3 name</dt>
            <dd>
                Term 3 description</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function firstChild(element) {
        for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var child = element.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                return child;
            }
        }
    }
    var terms = document.getElementById("terms");

    firstChild(terms).className += " first";

</script>

</html>
```

Reference:

```
nodeType Constants

        ELEMENT_NODE                :  1
        ATTRIBUTE_NODE              :  2
        TEXT_NODE                   :  3
        CDATA_SECTION_NODE          :  4
        ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE       :  5
        ENTITY_NODE                 :  6
        PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE :  7
        COMMENT_NODE                :  8
        DOCUMENT_NODE               :  9
        DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE          : 10
        DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE      : 11
        NOTATION_NODE               : 12
```

Comment: Thanks Sky Sanders. Is there any way to make it shorter?

Comment: @glister - not that I can see. actually, if anything, this snippet should probably be a bit longer, including guards that the element passed in is, in fact, a dom element etc.  in my experience, shorter is highly overrated. clarity of purpose is to be cherished in any code.

Comment: ok, I will try to use it a bit later and accept if works. Thanks again.

Comment: Does it add a class for a first child element?

Comment: I would recommend learning just a bit about JavaScript first. Do not blindly use snippets, understand them beforehand. Otherwise, you're doomed.

Comment: @glister - what fyodor says is correct. While I am happy to provide guidance, e.g. how to get the first child of an element, if your level of understanding of javascript is such that you cannot tell if it adds a classname you really do need to learn a bit more about js. In this case, googling how to add a classname to an element would be a good start. Cheers...